# java: join all hashmaps from an array list

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I have an aray list of hashmaps and I'd like to merge these hashmaps into a single one (keys should be unique). How would I have to do it? Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: create a root hashmap, traverse the list, for every hashmap go through every (key,value) pair add it to the root hashmap. You are going to decide what to do if you find a repeated key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way to do it would be to create a new instance of `HashMap ubermap`, iterate over the `ArrayList<HashMap>` and call [`putAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29) method of ubermap, one map at a time. A smart optimization would be to give a large initial capacity to `ubermap` in question so you would avoid many rehash calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate trought `Map.Entry` entries from your hash maps. You can get entries using `entrySet()` method.
Code should look like this:

```
public static <X,Y> Map<X,Y> test(Collection<Map<X,Y>> maps){
    HashMap<X,Y> result = new HashMap<X,Y>();
    for (Map<X,Y> singleMap:maps){
        for(Map.Entry<X,Y> entry:singleMap.entrySet()){
            result.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**UPD**: Many users wisely advised to use `putAll` method, but I forgot about it. So it will be better to use this code:

```
   public static <X,Y> Map<X,Y> test(Collection<Map<X,Y>> maps){
        HashMap<X,Y> result = new HashMap<X,Y>();
        for (Map<X,Y> singleMap:maps){
            result.putAll(singleMap);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the [Map.putAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29) function

Answer (score 0):

`Map` has method `putAll(Map m)`. Iterate over your list and do `putAll` on a result map for every entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for-each loop and add maps one by one from list in one hashmap using [HashMap.putAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29)

Answer (score 0):

loop through `list` and add all the maps to resultant map using [`putAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way:

1. Create a new (big) hashmap that will contain the merged key-value
   pairs
2. Iterate through your list
3. For each item of your list, iterate through the hashmap in question
4. For each value of the hashmap, add the pair in the (big) hashmap